# Control Less Window gets stuck in Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows

The dialer software of my ISP that connects to my wi-fi network. While connecting it creates a control-less windows which gets stuck in the middle of the my win7 desktop screen and does not goes off. I cannot close it or minimize it as there are no controls on it.

I want to know how to minimize or close the windows without killing the app via Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

There's no screenshot I can see, but usually pressing Windows + D or clicking on the rectangle in the bottom right hides all programs even if they don't have controls

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> with the window active. This is assuming there's at least some sort of control box, even if it's hidden.

You may even see a context menu appear after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Tim's suggestion to show the Desktop using <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't always work, as it could restore all minimised windows when you choose another application again.